# How to hide iAd in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, iad, appdelegate, banner

There is code to view banner in AppDelegate.m:

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone && [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height == 960.){
    bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:
                  CGRectMake(0, 25, 320, 80)];
}
else{
        bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]initWithFrame:
                      CGRectMake(0, 25, 320, 80)];
        // Optional to set background color to clear color
        [bannerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [viewController.view addSubview: bannerView];

}
```

How I can hide banner on GameLayerView? And then freshly show it after gameover. Should I write something in GameLayer.m?

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the ad by doing something like this:

```
-(void)hideBannerView{

    if (!_adBannerViewIsVisible){
        return;
    }

    if (bannerView){
        _adBannerViewIsVisible = false;

        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

        CGRect frame = bannerView.frame;

        frame.origin.x = 0.0f;
        frame.origin.y = -bannerView.frame.size.height ;

        bannerView.frame = frame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
```

Just don't forget to make a `BOOL` variable `_adBannerViewIsVisible`somewhere, probably in the header file. Then just call `[self hideBannerView]` when you want to hide the ads.